# How to determine the max. no. of clients that my web server can handle?

Tags: php

i need to compare performance of 3 different computers each running a web server. My idea is that given same php script to process on each server, the one able to serve largest no. of clients at given load limit  will be the most powerful one.

To implement this, i have a single php script which basically does some  heavy maths calculations. I am maintaining clients count as a static value. The script will run infinitely until say the cpu load is 95%. when the load reaches 95% the script should stop for all clients. 
 And at this limit, the one system having largest clients count will be the best performer.

A general structure of this php script is as :

```
static $clients_count=0;
static $sys_load=0;

//increment clients_count
$clients_count++;

while(sys_load<=95)
{
do_heavy_maths();

//calculate current cpu load 
sys_load=get_cpu_load();
}

echo "No. of max. clients this server handled: $clients_count";
```

So now i have a few questions :

1. is my approach of comparing CPU peformances correct . (PS i have to use web based 
   benchmarking only) ?
2. How to determine the no. of clients connected to my server ?
3. Pls provide a better way to find cpu load. (It's hard to draw a max. cpu limit using load_averages
   that one can get by reading from /proc/loadavg).

Thanx..

Comment: you never factor in max client allow in web server (like apache)

Comment: May be so. But my question is not about web server factorization but it's about cpu load. I just want to know how many times this script can run parallely till load reaches 95%. And when this happens i will get the no. of connections. Correct me if i am wrong..

Comment: what if your server can handle 100 connections before CPU load is 95% but your web server only allow 50 max concurrent connection? (then your testing is never will be fruitful)

Comment: Remember that a good deal of the load in a web application is IO. Testing using a CPU-heavy script might not be representative of real-world performance.

Comment: I'm also not sure about `static $clients_count = 0;` unless it's just a placeholder for some other method of sharing the data. How do static variables in PHP behave when using prefork? (Which I believe is the recommended way to set up Apache *especially* with PHP.)

Answer (score 1):

Trying to do this from inside, is less accurate than running an external benchmarking tool.

Remember that php core has several triggers that can avoid cpu consumption or limit it.

With opcode cache this can run faster, several other aspects.

Check some tools at: http://www.opensourcetesting.org/performance.php

I strongly believe PHP does not suit as well as writing that on a raw memory/cpu access language with a closer memory and cpu management like C.

Comment: i agree with u but i cant help it. I am required to write a php based benchmarking tool. Though i will write a C version of this tool but as of now i have to go with php only..thanx anyway..

Answer (score 1):

Think it is nice to try. Sounds like a fun project.

Unfortunately but this is not realistic load testing. Configuration settings will heavily influence the capacity a single script can use. You are only running single threaded while webservers strongly rely on multi-threaded capacity. Also other influences like the active load, other processes, allocations etc. all influence. Not even to take in account network speeds.

Loads are normally indicated as a number like 2.0. This actually doesn't say anything about the load since it depends on the number of CPU cores which is your real capacity.

For real benchmarking use real tools like: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html and many other professional solutions.

1. *is my approach of comparing CPU peformances correct . (PS i have to use web based benchmarking only) ?*
   No, as explained above.
2. *How to determine the no. of clients connected to my server ?*
   That will only be done if you know what the clients actually do. A server for delivering only static files should be setup totally different compared to a server running complex script at every request.
3. *Pls provide a better way to find cpu load.* *It's hard to draw a max. cpu limit using load_averages that one can get by reading from /proc/loadavg.*
   In a seperate process log the over-all load and log it. Put it next to your testing log and you see the influences. To create this limit the only way in PHP is exec a command, parse the feedback. Mention the note above about nr. of CPU's, cores etc. of which you have to take care of. It is not just a percentage.

Comment: thanx alot Franken..great answer..and i agree that this test in no way can be true as u have mentioned but my idea was simple that if u have to compare 3 systems using a single php script what way would u go? As such i looking at  http://www.opensourcetesting.org/performance.php for real world metric tools.